# Is there a better way to insert values from arrays into SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server-2008, insert

I am trying to store rows in a SQL Server 2008 table for a junkyard about documentation in all vehicles; I will run this program once a month that I receive a list with information for all vehicles. I know I can write a text file and do a "bulk insert" from a file.

However, I just wondered if there is a way to insert information stored in string arrays directly into SQL Server.

Right now I am doing a for loop and running 500 query commands to insert them, and for 500 records it only takes about 4 seconds the whole process.

I would like to know **if there is a better way** to insert the information from arrays directly without using a for-loop 500 times?

The code below works perfectly fine for me, however I would not like to use that kind of spaghetti code if there exists a better way to do it. Thanks in advance!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [TESTCATALOG].[dbo].[TITLES] VALUES ('" + TitleNum[i] + "','" + VIN[i] + "','" + DateIssued[i] + "')", con);
    myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries, not concatenating values.

Comment: Use parametrized queries

Comment: for starters, try moving 'con.Open()' and 'con.Close()' outside of the loop.

Comment: Also, if you're don't care about the results of a query, use 'myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) (TVP) to insert lists directly through a stored procedure.

> Table-valued parameters are a new parameter type in SQL Server 2008. Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many parameters.

This will also avoid the SQL Injection vulnerability currently present in your code.

See [Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server 2008 (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) on MSDN to see how to call a stored procedure with a TVP with C#:

```
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
                                                           "@tvpNewCategories", 
                                                           addedCategories);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use linq to sql or linq to entities to achieve this in a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.  The SqlBulkCopy class requires your data be available as `DataRow[]`, `DataTable` or `IDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2008 onwards, you can use a table valued variable.

[See "Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Parameterized SQL Statement" in MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use dataadapter for insert or update. 
first add rows in a datatable in yor for loop then call dataadapter.update with datatable